# Confusion about initWithNibName and loadView

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Is the *initWithNibName* always called whenever programmatically or IB?

Example:

I have two viewController, one named PhotoViewController, the other named ViewController. 
The PhotoViewController creates view programmatically, but with initWithNibName uncommented.

Here is my PhotoViewController.m:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    NSLog(@"loadView in PhotoView");
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen 
                                                  mainScreen].applicationFrame]; 
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; 
    self.view = view; 
    [view release]; 
}

// Loading views from a nib file.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    NSLog(@"PhotoViewController initWithNibName=%@",nibNameOrNil);
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

Here is my call in ViewController.m

```
- (void) doSearchFlickr
{
    PhotoViewController *pController  = [[PhotoViewController alloc]init];
    [self.view addSubview:pController.view];
    [pController release];
}
```

Then I see something confusing me in the log:

```
2011-10-23 10:52:52.151 TableViewPG[1192:b303] PhotoViewController initWithNibName=(null)
2011-10-23 10:52:52.153 TableViewPG[1192:b303] loadView in PhotoView
```

According to the ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS on page 30, if I override loadView programmatically, initWithNibName should not be called.

Is there any flaw(s) in my logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-[UIViewController init]` just executes `[self initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]`.  You can easily check this by putting a breakpoint in your `-[PhotoViewController initWithNibName:bundle:]` and looking at the call stack.

Your `-[PhotoViewController loadView]` is fine.

The [*View Controller Programming Guide for iOS*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS.pdf) doesn't say anything about `initWithNibName:bundle:` on page 30.

Comment: Thanks. There's a misunderstanding on the Guide's words. I know the concept now.